# MapStruct mapping of multiple parameters

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
@Mapping(target = "content.shortText", qualifiedByName = "shortText")
@Mapping(target = "content.longText", qualifiedByName = "longText")
EntityDto mapToDto(Entity entity, String shortText, String longText);
```

I want to map second und third parameter in the @mappings as the source , but it never works.

If I do `mapToDto(myEntity, "Hello", "WorldLong")`
Hello should be mapped to  `target = "content.shortText"` and WorldLong to `target = "content.longText"` but it does not work

Comment: Have you tried to use "source" insted of "qualifiedByName" ?

Comment: @Toni26 Did source work for you?

Comment: In my case it didn not work. But I think the reason was in the object entity was a member that had the same name like the parameters shortText and longText. So maybe if you name parameter to e.g. shortTextParam and longTextParam maybe it works.

Answer (score 1):

qualifiedByName is used to call a method annotated with @Named.
You should use the source parameter.

```
@Mapping(target = "content.shortText", source= "shortText")
@Mapping(target = "content.longText", source= "longText")
EntityDto mapToDto(Entity entity, String shortText, String longText);
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mappings-with-several-source-parameters).
Here is an example from the page:

```
@Mapper
public interface AddressMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "description", source = "person.description")
    @Mapping(target = "houseNumber", source = "hn")
    DeliveryAddressDto personAndAddressToDeliveryAddressDto(Person person, Integer hn);
}
```